# Prove $(1+x)^p+(1-x)^p \ge 2(1+x^p)$ for $0\le x\le1$ and real number $p\ge2$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

I don't know how to prove the following questions: If $p\ge2$ is real, then
$$
(1+x)^p+(1-x)^p \ge 2(1+x^p) \quad \text{for } 0\le x\le1;
$$
if $1\le p<2$, then opposite direction of the inequality holds.

I try to find a convex function but I could not. And I take the derivative of function $f(x):=(1+x)^p+(1-x)^p-2x^p$ but it still doesn't work.

**EDIT**
I tried the "[Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)", but it could only be workable for the case $p\ge2$ but not for the case $1\le p<2$.

Comment: What about using binomial theorem

Comment: @openspace I tried before, the binomial theorem can only solves the case $p\ge2$ but be failure for the case $1\le p<2$...

Comment: Is this related? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson's_inequalities

Comment: @Siminore Thanks a lot! You are right, I am reading Clarkson's paper "Uniformly convex spaces". It seems rather complex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lemma. for $f(x)=x^k$. if $k\geq 1$ then for $a,b>0$,then $a^k+b^k\leq (a+b)^k$. if $0\leq k\leq 1$, then $a^k+b^k\geq (a+b)^k$.

proof.when $k\geq 1$, then we have $(\frac{a}{a+b})^k\leq\frac{a}{a+b}$ and $(\frac{b}{a+b})^k\leq\frac{b}{a+b}$ for $\frac{a}{a+b}\leq 1$, $\frac{b}{a+b}\leq 1. $

Hence:$(\frac{a}{a+b})^k+(\frac{b}{a+b})^k\leq \frac{a}{a+b}+\frac{b}{a+b}=1$,which implies:$a^k+b^k\leq (a+b)^k$. In the similar way, we can prove if $0\geq k\leq 1$, then $a^k+b^k\geq (a+b)^k$.

Back to the problem:Set $f(x)= (1+x)^p+(1-x)^p-2(1+x^p)$,we have:
$$
f'(x)= p\times (1+x)^{p-1}-p\times (1-x^{p-1})-2p\times x^{p-1}
$$

When $p\geq 2$, then $p-1 \geq 1$.

Then for $0\leq x \leq 1$:
$$
(1+\frac{1}{x})^{p-1}\geq 2^{p-1}+(\frac{1}{x}-1)^{p-1}\geq 2+(\frac{1}{x}-1)^{p-1}
$$
which implies $f'(x)\geq 0$

Thus $f(x)\geq f(0)=0$

Applying the same method, when $1\leq p <2$, we have:
$$
f(x)\leq f(1)=2^p-2\times (1+1)\leq 0.
$$

Comment: Good, your lemma is useful, thank you.